# construct string from indices in C

Tags: c, string, char

When I construct a string like this:

```
char string[1] = {'a'};
printf("%s", string)
```

it returns a `a4`. 
Why is there a four at the end? How can I get rid of it?

I choose this method because I need to make a string from character indexes, such as `char array[4] = {string[i],string[j],string[k]};`.

Comment: you forgot about trailing 0

Comment: You're missing a null-terminator: `char string[2] = {'a', '\0'};`. The `'\0'` is equivalent to `0`.

Comment: Since there is no null-terminator, it can not be treated as C-STring. However, you can use `printf("%.*s", (int)sizeof(string), string);` 
 instead of `printf("%s", string)`. Or `char string[1] = {'a'};` --> `char string[2] = {'a'};`

Comment: `printf("%c\n", string[0])` :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you could simplify this to `char string[] = {'a', '\0'};`

Comment: I think it will be null-terminated if in a statically allocated storage...

Comment: to add to above in C strings are simply, a one denominational array. to make it feel special you add that null at the end, or you represent it by " " . Please dont call your variable string simply change it to my_string, or sexy_string, anything you want

Comment: @BlooB-- strings in C are not simply one-dimensional arrays. They are character arrays that are null-terminated. They _must_ be null-terminated. The `'\0'` is part of the string, and if it is not present, the array is simply an array, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string should end with terminating char '\0'
You can do it by:

```
char string[2] = {'a','\0'};
```

Or:

```
char string[] = "a";
```

Answer (score 1):

"strings" in C are essentially arrays of characters ending with the \0 character (null terminated).
So if you want an array of characters, what you did is fine, but it is not a "string". Dont try to print it as such.
If you would also like to print it or treat it as a "string", then increase it's length by 1, and add a `'\0'` char at the end.

Comment: Why is there a four at the end? Good if you can explain this also.

Comment: The data in memory after the array you defined happens to be 4 and 0 (there may be other numbers in between which don't have a visual effect on the output)

Comment: @ShashwatKumar It's just garbage value.. why do you care?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion specification `%s` is used to output strings that is a sequence of characters terminated by a zero character.

The array declared this way

```
char string[1] = {'a'};
```

does not contain a string.

So to output its elements you need to specify the exact number of characters you are going to output. For example

```
printf("%*.*s", 1, 1, string);
```

Otherwise reserve one more element in the array for the terminating zero and use the conversion specification `%s`. For example

```
char string[2] = {'a'};
printf( "%s", string );
```